# Content not rendering in conditional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So currently i have a react component. I have declared an array which contains a series of objects for some sample data. As the initial state for 'currentStep' is 0, I expect the  `<div>Screen 1</div>`  to render, however, all i get is a blank screen.

Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

/**
 * sample data to pass through
 */

const contents =
  [
    { title: 'First Screen', step: 0, children: <div>Screen 1</div> },
    { title: 'Second Screen', step: 1, children: <div>Screen 2</div> },
    { title: 'Third Screen', step: 2, children: <div>Screen 3</div> },
  ];

class Wizard extends Component {
  state = {
    currentStep: 0,
  }

  Content = () => {
    const { currentStep } = this.state;
    contents.map((content) => {
      if (content.step === currentStep) { return content.children; }
      return null;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.Content()}</div>     
    );
  }
}

export default Wizard;
```

Comment: did you try to console.log(this.Content()) ? 
Any error messages in the console ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return your map in Content. Right now you are returning nothing. For ex:

```
Content = () => {
  const { currentStep } = this.state;
  return contents.map((content) => {
    if (content.step === currentStep) { return content.children; }
    return null;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Content` function isn't actually returning anything, but your *map* function is. If you `return contents.map(...)`, then you should get what you are expecting.

Comment: added return infront of contents.map, now it works :D